# How to convert (key,array(value)) to (key,value) in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD like below:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array((1,Array((3,4),(4,5))),(2,Array((4,2),(4,4),(3,9)))))
```

which is `RDD[(Int,Array[(Int,Int)])]`  I want to get the result like `RDD[(Int,(Int,Int)]` by some operations such as `flatMap` or else. In this example, the result should be:

```
(1,(3,4))
(1,(4,5))
(2,(4,2))
(2,(4,4))
(2,(3,9))
```

I am quite new to spark, so what could I do to achieve this? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

you can use flatMap in your case like this :

```
val newRDD: RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))] = rdd1
.flatMap { case (k, values) => values.map(v => (k, v))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that as RDD as `rd`. Use below code to get the data as you want

`rdd1.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1,y)))`

Internal `map` method in `flatmap` read `x._2` which is array and read each value of array at a time as `y`. After that flat map will give them as separate items. `x._1` is the first value in the RDD.